# Not able to view source code of this website

Tags: javascript, html, css, inspect

I'm not able to view source code of some websites like this one:
https://quube.exchange/.

When I right click and then click on "View source", only some codes appear which are not the right source code of the page.

Using inspect element I'm able to view the full code but I need the original source code before JavaScript renders appear on inspect element.

Comment: what you're seeing is the source as downloaded from the server

Comment: You are seeing the correct source code which is not the same as you see when inspecting because that is the code that has been rendered with Javascript client side.

Comment: yes but for some sections when I copy the code from developer console it doesn't work the same as original website in my localhost

Answer (score 1):

If you scroll down a bit (upto TOKENIZE UNIQUENESS section) and then try to check view source, it will work. I just checked.

Answer (score 0):

In html only iframe is used, These whole website loaded in iframe so you can not able to see view source.. if html content is written then we can see view source..

Comment: so it's not possible to have the exact clone of this website on my localhost?

Comment: You can take code from inspect element copy code from inspect element